# 2 tasks - create tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm struggling with 2 exercises

**1.** create table Month which one will include 2 data: date of hire for the employee and the name of the month, when he started the job

This is my idea for this:

```
    CREATE TABLE month (
      hire date VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      name of month VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    );
```

I'm receiving syntax error

**2.** Create table with columns: name, last name, subject, the date of the test.
The nest step is to add 5 records. Each column should be field.

My idea:

```
  CREATE TABLE Data (
      name VARCHAR (25)NOT NULL,
      surname VARCHAR(25)NOT NULL,
      subject CHAR(25)NOT NULL,
      day DATE NOT NULL
    );
    
    INSERT INTO dane(name, last name, subject, day)
     values ('Marta', 'Smith', 'Math', Monday);
     
    INSERT INTO dane(name, last name, subject, day)
     values ('Kasia', 'Kowalska', 'SQL', Wendesday);
```

What i'm receiving: Syntax error in field definition.
I was trying a few times and both doesn't work.
can you help me?

Comment: You have spaces in there. Use underscores in the names instead.

Comment: The inserts should reference the table, dane is not the name of the table, yo have named it Data

Comment: Also just as a sugestion, everything you put into a database table is "data", it is better to give the tables a more significant name.

Comment: Multiple problems here.
#1 - as @cst1992 said. column names cannot have spaces. hire date should be hire_date or hiredate same with name of month should be nameofmonth or name_of_month
#2 Insert into `data` not `dane`.
#3 `Monday` and `Wednesday` is not a value that you can add. if its a Date datatype you have to add value in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
#4 there is no `last name` in data. its `surname`

Answer (score 1):

1) your field name cant have spaces, unless they are between ticks '`' also you have one extra comma at the end. And `hire_date` should be type `DATE` not `VARCHAR`

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NWS65528)

```
CREATE TABLE month (
      hire_date VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      name_of_month VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    );
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE month (
      `hire date` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `name of month` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    );
```

Second Part

1. your table is Data not dane
2. your field is `surname`, not `last name`
3. Monday isnt a valid date

.

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
  name VARCHAR (25)NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR(25)NOT NULL,
  subject CHAR(25)NOT NULL,
  day DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Data(name, surname, subject, day)
 values ('Marta', 'Smith', 'Math', '2017-12-01');

INSERT INTO Data(name, surname, subject, day)
 values ('Kasia', 'Kowalska', 'SQL', '2017-12-02');
```

Comment: thank you! It was so easy! I feel bad, that i didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in the name, it'll give you an error when the next part of your name starts. Eliminate the spaces in the names and it'll be fine.